# Webbrowser control handling javascript: popup

Tags: .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

My software handles navigation to target=_new through this function

```
Private Sub Web1_NewWindow(...) Handles Web1.NewWindow
    Web1.Navigate(Web1.StatusText)
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Which allows me to open any new windows inside the same webbrowser control. However, when navigating to a "javascript:" link that creates a new popup, I get the following message because it is trying to navigate to that page:

```
The requested resource is in use. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700AA)
```

How can I make it open a javascript popup in the webbrowser control?

The link looks like this:

```
javascript:Dpy.ITQPopup('100',255,'2932 NTYwNDUwMTA0MDYzMDM);3094 V0FZ','-357933312',0,0)
```

Comment: That is not possible.  The Automation interface can only deal with popups, not Javascript alert() chatter.  Best to find a way to avoid that horrible error message, I'd say, putting it a friendly window isn't going to make the user any happier.

Comment: hey Hans, I'm not talking about javascript:alert(), i'm talking about a new window created as a result of a script by clicking the link "javascript:function(xyz)".

Comment: Same problem.  Works just lovely in my favorite browser's "open link in new tab" context menu entry as well.  Not.

Comment: What if I implemented tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what exactly is inside the `javascript:` link, it may or may not work. For example:

```
<body>

<!-- These work -->

<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Test 0</a><br>
<a href="javascript:navigate('http://www.example.com')" target="_blank">Test 1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:'<b>hello</b> from new page!'" target="_blank">Test 2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:''" target="_blank">Test 3</a><br>
<a href="javascript:TestFunc()" target="_blank">Test 4</a><br>

<!-- This does not work -->

<a href="javascript:open('http://www.example.com')" target="_blank">Test 5</a><br>


<script>
function TestFunc()
{
    return "<b>TestFunc</b> result.";
}
</script>

</body>
```

Here's the code that handles `NewWindow` event. This code is in C#, unfortunately I don't know VB.NET good enough to properly translate it.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
    // generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
    // and add as a reference to the project

    var activex = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)this.webBrowser.ActiveXInstance;

    activex.NewWindow += delegate(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
    {
        Processed = true;
        object flags = Flags;
        object targetFrame = Type.Missing;
        object postData = PostData != null ? PostData : Type.Missing;
        object headers = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Headers)? Headers.ToString() : Type.Missing;
        activex.Navigate(URL, ref flags, ref targetFrame, ref postData, ref headers);
    };

    this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost:81/new-window-test.html");
}
```

Now, if you *really* need to make **Test 5** work, it's still possible. The problem with it is there are in fact two navigations, the second one is nested, which might be the reason for error `0x800700AA`. The trick is to return from `NewWindow` event first, and then do the navigation:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
    // generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
    // and add as a reference to the project

    var activex = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)this.webBrowser.ActiveXInstance;

    activex.NewWindow += delegate(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
    {
        Processed = true;
        object flags = Flags;
        object targetFrame = Type.Missing;
        object postData = PostData != null ? PostData : Type.Missing;
        object headers = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Headers) ? Headers.ToString() : Type.Missing;
        SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
        {
            activex.Navigate(URL, ref flags, ref targetFrame, ref postData, ref headers);
        }, null);
    };

    this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost:81/new-window-test.html");
}
```

Tested with IE10.

**[UPDATE]**

Try this (verified):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ActiveX As SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1

    Private Sub NavigateOnNewWindow(NewWindowUrl As Object)
        Me.ActiveX.Navigate(NewWindowUrl.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewWindow(URL As String,
                          Flags As Integer,
                          TargetFrameName As String,
                          ByRef PostData As Object,
                          Headers As String,
                          ByRef Processed As Boolean)
        Processed = True
        System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(AddressOf NavigateOnNewWindow, URL)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Init DocumentText, otherwise Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance is null, this is different from C#
        Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = String.Empty
        Me.ActiveX = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
        AddHandler Me.ActiveX.NewWindow, AddressOf NewWindow
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:81/new-window-test.html")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I added the link to the original post, maybe you can help me identify whether it's test 5 or not.

Comment: Does `ITQPopup(...)` return anything? Does it call `window.open` inside?

Comment: I just traced the functions and yes, window.open is called!

Comment: Then yes, it's the case #5 in my test, because of `window.open`. I updated the answer with some VB.NET code, give it a try.

Comment: I adjusted the code and when I click the link now, it results in some sort of endless loop which keeps the cursor going from arrow to busy intermittently until it displays a 404 (and subs can only be stacked in vb btw :)

Comment: My VB is very rusty, sorry :] If you really need to make it work, you'd probably need to use low level interfaces from `SHDocVw` like I did.

Comment: Error HRESULT E_FAIL and Catastrophic Failure when creating the ShDocVw WebBrowser (I'm guessing this is a COM issue)

Comment: You do not create it, rather you obtain it from existing WinForms `WebBrowser` via `webBrowser.ActiveXInstance`. I've posted a VB.NET sample that actually works. Note how the `URL` is passed over to `NavigateOnNewWindow`.

Comment: You, my friend, are a **boss**, thank you very much - and to whoever else is implementing this, **MAKE SURE!!!!** you do not have a `NewWindow` event for the WebBrowser control as it takes precedence over the `ActiveX.NewWindow` event.