# AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser CanGoBack/CanGoForward missing like in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, axwebbrowser

I am using AxWebBrowser control and i need to implement an interface that indicates if the user can navigate back or forward.

In the "normal" WebBrowser control i had the booleans CanGoBack/CanGoForward.

Does AxWebBrowser have similar bools or do i have the chance to implement it in another way?

Comment: You can still access the underlying `AxWebBrowser` via `webBrowser.ActiveXInstance`, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18822779/1768303).

Comment: I dont have an ActiveXInstance in AxWebBrowser object.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question when commenting, but I believe I've got it right in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to handle [DWebBrowserEvents2::CommandStateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and track the state [CSC_NAVIGATEFORWARD/CSC_NAVIGATEBACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) commands.