# WebBrowser Invoking Click is opening Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

In my application, I need to click on a HtmlElement in a WebBrowser from inside a thread.

The current code from within the thread is

```
 Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
        {
      foreach (HtmlElement element in progridbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td"))
              if (element == myElement)
                        {
                            element.SetAttribute("id", "lc");
                            progridbrowser.Document.GetElementById("lc").InvokeMember("click");
                        }
                }));
```

When I Invoke the Click method, it opens a new window in Internet Explorer, what I want it to do is make the **WebBrowser** navigate to the URL the Click method will open.

Comment: Most likely, the parent form of the button (or the link) you programmatically click has `target=_blank` attribute, in which case a new IE window is the normal  behavior. You can verify that by clicking the same element manually. If that's the case, [here is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20942721/1768303) how you might be able to solve it.

Comment: The code that opens up the new tab is run when a table cell is clicked, it's in jQuery written like this [link](http://codepen.io/notarypublic/pen/ylqCb)

Comment: That solution works with JavaScript-based links too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18822779/1768303

Comment: Thanks @Noseratio, worked like a charm!